# Devise sign-up form on home-page?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How can I display `devise` sign-up form on home-page with other content in Rails 3.2.3?

Right now the form is available under `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up` but I want it under `http://localhost:3000` with other content.

Comment: `root :to => 'users#sign_up'` ?

Comment: nope. it just displays the sign-up form i want other content too..

Comment: devise crates views you can modify: `rails generate devise:views` puts the views in the app/views/sessions folder. You can either modify them or copy the code somewhere else and make sure that it routes back to the sessions controller.

Answer (score 1):

If you want other content with your sign_up form, you need to build that content around your form. You also have to map your routes to display that form (with the additional material) as your home page.